# How to get the result by define divide function using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
def set_div(a,b):
    if a==0:
        if b==0:
            return 0
        else:
            return 10**6
    else:
        return b/a
```

df:

```
    a       b
0   0.0     0.0
1   30000.0 0.0
2   0.0     0.0
3   32700.0 10000.0
4   51700.0 0.0
```

dtypes of col a and b are `float64`.

```
df['c'] = df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x:set_div(x[0],x[1]))
```

but it returns `KeyError: (0, 'occurred at index a')`.

I don't understand the error, please explain and how to get my result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want to use custom function working for each row need [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x :set_div(x['a'],x['b']), axis=1)
```

Another solution with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is vectorized, so better performance in large DataFrame:

```
m1 = df['a'] == 0
m2 = df['b'] == 0
df['c'] = np.select([m1 & ~m2, m1 & m2], [10**6, 0], df['b'] / df['a'])
print (df)
         a        b        c
0      0.0      0.0  0.00000
1  30000.0      0.0  0.00000
2      0.0      0.0  0.00000
3  32700.0  10000.0  0.30581
4  51700.0      0.0  0.00000
```

**Performance**:

```
#[50000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [113]: %timeit df['c'] = np.select([m1 & ~m2, m1 & m2], [10**6, 0], df['b'] / df['a'])
1.85 ms ± 32.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [114]: %timeit df['c1'] = df.apply(lambda x :set_div(x['a'],x['b']), axis=1)
1.01 s ± 17.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want directly by using numpy [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in this way:

```
df['c'] = numpy.where(df.a == 0, numpy.where(df.b == 0, 0, 10**6), df.b/df.a)

print(df)
```

The output is:

```
       a      b        c
0      0      0  0.00000
1  30000      0  0.00000
2      0      0  0.00000
3  32700  10000  0.30581
4  51700      0  0.00000
```

If you want to use your defined method itself, then you will have to add the parameter `axis=1` when calling the `apply` method so that it operates row-wise instead of column-wise.